# Android Device Monitor only works when running as admin

Tags: android, android-studio

When attempting to run Android Device Monitor (from both Android Studio and Command Line), I get this error: https://gist.github.com/plumdot/7624f74ee922cb4b8865

Environment: Windows8.1 64bit

I'm able to run Android Device Monitor when I run Android Studio as an administrator.

I would rather not start up Android Studio as an administrator every time.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Things I've tried:

- Uninstall JDK & JRE / install JDK8 & JRE8
- Uninstall JDK & JRE / install JDK7 & JRE7
- Double check my PATH variables.
- Double check my project structure is pointing to the correct SDK and JDK in Android Studio.
- Check similar questions on StackOverflow, none of which has panned out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Vista 32-bit. I could not get the emulator to launch when I was logged in as a user.

So I logged in as 'administrator' and installed Android Studio. I created a 'HelloWorld' app and ran it. The emulator ran = success!

I then logged out and logged back in as a user and ran studio.exe. Damn emulator didn't run.

While logged in as user I changed the properties of 'studio.exe' so that users had all privileges (full control, modify, read & execute, read, write). I then launched studio.exe.

I STILL couldn't get the emulator to work. So I exited studio.

As a last resort I right-clicked on studio.exe and choose the "Run as Administrator" --- this worked. The emulator works!

Lesson: Change the permissions for user and then run studio.exe as admin, but you don't have to login as admin.

I hope this works for you.

Sarri